# Ошибка при вызове функции (Python)

Tags: python

Мне нужно создать функцию, принимающую список, и возвращающую максимальное значение из этого списка. Пробовал разными способами передать список как аргумент, ошибки те же.
Реально ли вообще передать именно список как аргумент, а не кортежи и словари? Поэтому `def fun(*a):` и `def fun(**a):` НЕ подойдут.

*Фрагмент неработающего кода:*

```
def fun(a):
    max = 0
    for i in a:
        if a[i] > max:
            max = a[i]
    return max
a = [1, 5, 8, 3, 2]

print(fun(a))
```

**Сама ошибка:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGkPH.png

Comment: что, по-вашему, получается в цикле for в переменной `a[i]` ? Вы ведь не индекса берете, а значения списка.

Comment: И текст ошибки в текстовом виде вставьте в вопрос. не надо ссылок ни на какие скриншоты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо так (индексы ведь вам не нужны)

```
for x in a:
    if x > max:
        max = x
```

либо так (если индексы для какой-то цели понадобятся)

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > max:
        max = a[i]
```

Кроме того, выбор нуля для начального значения максимума не сработает при наличии отрицательных. Лучше использовать первый элемент.

Ну а про встроенную функцию `max` вы же знаете?

Comment: про ```max``` слышал, но писал раньше на C++ привык делать все от руки, да и пока это не в напряг, лишняя тренировка

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fun(a):
    maxx = 0
    print(a)
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        if a[i] > maxx:
            maxx = a[i]
    return maxx
a = [1, 5, 8, 3, 2]

print(fun(a))
```

Вам надо поочереди проверять число ли в списке больше максимального.

Comment: а если в списке все элементы - отрицательные?